# destructring an object method returning undefined at the end

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let obj={
a:1,
b:2,
c:function(){
    console.log('hi') 
},
}
const {c}=obj
console.log(c())
```

this object method return undefined with the text hi in console, but the when I tried the it as a function it doesn't return undefined, what am I missing here?

Comment: `console.log()` returns `undefined`. So when you call `console.log("hello")` in the console, you'd see `"hello"` (the argument provided) and `undefined` (return value of the expression).

Comment: Also, the `c()` function doesn't return anything, so `console.log(c())` will itself print `undefined`

Comment: oh ok,thanks brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
console.log(c())
```

to just this:

```
c()
```

because `c()` already does its own logging and the extra `console.log()` wrapped around it logs the return value of calling `c()` which is `undefined` because it has no declared return value.  This, that extra `console.log()` wrapped around logs that `undefined` return value.